# Odd mouse behavior in only some apps and websites

Tags: windows, mouse

TL;DR there seems to be some sort of tracking issue with my mouse in some applications - how can I fix this?

So because of schooling from home, I had to download Autodesk Inventor to work on my drafting class projects. Immediately, I noticed this one weird behavior: any dialog boxes within that program appears about 1/4 of the screen below the mouse. Mouse location *within the dialog boxes only* would only be registered in that location, 1/4 of the screen below where it should be. Additionally, when those dialog boxes are open, I can only interact with elements within those dialog boxes (but with elements outside the dialog boxes simultaneously, as if the dialog boxes are tracking the wrong mouse position) when I am moving my mouse. At the time, that problem hasn't appeared in any other programs (and the exact same program worked perfectly on my laptop), so I thought that it was just hardware support that was lacking.

But then I noticed just now that on the Trello website that the scrollbar behavior, more specifically scrollbars added into the webpage content itself also had similar behavior; it appears to register any left-clicks about 100 pixels below where they should be registered. Also, this worked fine before on this exact same computer a few days ago, even. What's going on here?